# How to block "Twitter’s Promoted Tweets" on iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, adblock

How could I block "Twitter’s Promoted Tweets"? I use the official iOS client. I also use the official OS X client, but so far didn't notice on OS X "Promoted Tweets".

Is the solution to switch to other iOS client? Which one without ads?

Comment: Twitter has to make money somehow. How you you expect them to keep the servers running?  You can't run Twitter on rainbows and sunshine.  Small price to pay for a great service.

Comment: Or, you can pay a slightly higher price for [an even better (and ad-free) service](http://join.app.net). :D

Comment: Rainbows and sunshine - Smaller price to pay would be if Twitter sponsored tweets were targeted more effectively, adding value to a great service, as opposed to adding value at any cost. Teething problems no doubt, but still slightly annoying when the promoted tweet holds no appeal. If I was using promoted tweets to promote a brand I would still have the same problem, except maybe I'd be more than slightly annoyed.

Comment: This would be fine on a question asking opinions on whether Twitter is doing well - but we're more interested in how to disable it - not the why or style of how twitter is being run. The chat rooms are a great place for this.

Comment: Evert reply to a Sponsored Tweet costs the Sponsor a sum of money. Simply reply with the hashtag #SPAMMER and the Sponsor pays. It just needs lots and lots of people to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter is injecting the promoted tweets into the stream. It's only a matter of time until they lean on every third-party app provider to stop filtering out the promoted tweets as this is how they're going to pay for the service.

In the short-term you can use a different client but in the long term all signs point to you being forced to see promoted tweets promoted tweets or leave Twitter.

Even in fall of 2013, most major third party twitter apps aren't showing promoted tweets. I use twitterrific and don't see promoted content in my streams.